# How to load excel into a MVC webpage and able to work in excel and export it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ms-office

I have a requirement of loading a excel sheet 2013 from the server to a mvc webpage. The user who logs in based on the permission parameters will be provided , in turn excel will refresh the data from datasource. Usually user will do the pivot reporting from the excel data and later he needs to export the report also.How I can achieve this ?

(I do not want to go for sharepoint !)

Answer (score 0):

We can read from excel files, write to excel files using EPPlus Nuget Package, we can show data in grid using table and/or CSS styling but your question said you need to read from data source and show as excel, similar to what Office Online does, then this is something only Office API's can do. If that is something you're after, then read the [Office 365 API Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/getting-started-Office-365-APIs).

EDIT: You can get access to the Office 365 Developer Options through enrollment on [Office Dev Center](http://dev.office.com/devprogram)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I went through the link, I have the licensed version of the Office 365 (Professional Plus 2013). Do the 'subscription with Azure AD' is free ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Syncfusion Spreadsheet control for this. You can import excel files into a browser and this control will render the excel sheet for you to edit like a pro.

**Control Features**: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejSpreadsheet

**Demo**: http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/spreadsheet/defaultfunctionalities

**JS Playground**:
http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/Sync_u32wutdj